# Pass a vector starting from index i by reference

Tags: c++11, pass-by-reference

I am writing a function in C++

```
int maxsubarray(vector<int>&nums)
```

say I have a vector

```
v={1,2,3,4,5}
```

I want to pass

```
{3,4,5}
```

to the function,i.e. pass the vector starting from index 2. In C I know I can call maxsubarray(v+2)
but in C++ it doesn't work. I can modify the function by adding start index parameter to make it work of course. Just want to know can I do it without modifying my original function?
THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try calling it with a temporary:

```
int myMax = maxsubarray(vector<int>(v.begin() + 2, v.end()));
```

That might require changing the function signature to

```
int maxsubarray(const vector<int> &nums);
```

since (I think) temporaries can't bind to non-`const` references, but that change should be *preferred* here if `maxsubarray` won't modify `nums`.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a temporary vector with the part you want to pass:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<int> v2(v.begin() + 2, v.end());
maxsubarray(v2);
```

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution is to make a new vector and pass that one instead. I definitely do not recommend that. The most idiomatic way is to make your function take iterators:

```
template<typename It>
It::value_type maxsubarray(It begin, It end) { ... }
```

and then use it like this:

```
std::vector<int> nums(...);
auto max = maxsubarray(begin(nums) + 2, end(nums));
```

Anything else involving copies, is just inefficient and not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Not without constructing another vector.

You can either build a new vector a pass it by reference to the function (but this might not be ideal from a performance point of view. You generally pass by reference to avoid unnecessary copies) or use pointers:

```
//copy the vector
std::vector<int> copy(v.begin()+2, v.end());
maxsubarray(copy);

//pass a pointer to the given element
int maxsubarray(int * nums) 
maxsubarray(&v[2]);
```